# Firestore nodejs modular SDK FieldValue syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have been tasked with updating a set of firebase cloud functions from the old namespace interface to the new modular interface. It seems pretty strait forward as described in https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-node-v10#typescript.

However the code har the following lines:

```
await firestoreDb.doc(`/${projectsPath}/${projectKey}`).update({
   roUids: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(uidOfUserToDelete),
   rwUids: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(uidOfUserToDelete),
});
```

I cannot find documentation about FieldValue. Should it still be accessed with the admin. interface as above and admin imported as:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
```

Or is there a new syntax for the modular SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-node-v10#use-modules-instead-of-namespaces), you should prefer to use the more specific modular entrypoints for Firestore. It shows, for example:

> Starting from v10, the Admin Node.js SDK offers multiple module entry points with named exports. We recommend developers to use these new entry points to access the various APIs of the SDK, as opposed to using the global admin namespace.
>
> ```
> // Import only what you need
> import { initializeApp, App } from 'firebase-admin/app';
> import { getAuth, UserRecord } from 'firebase-admin/auth';
> ```

FieldValue is just another thing to import from `firebase-admin/firestore`:

```
import { FieldValue } from "firebase-admin/firestore"

// use FieldValue.arrayRemove(...)
```

Comment: `firebase-admin/firestore` is for nodejs right?  Where is it on the modular web api?  I've tried `firebase/firestore` but no luck.   God there's far too many firebase packages, it's impossible to google.  And the docs don't show imports, just the function call.  I've found the same issue with the logical `or` method.  Its documented but no idea where it comes from.  Its not where `where`, `query` etc comes from..